# BinaryWriter to overwrite an existing file c#

Tags: c#, jpeg, binarywriter

To write a picture on the memory of my pocket pc i use the following code:

```
pic = (byte[])myPicutureFromDatabase;
using (var fs = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)))
{
    fs.Write(pic);
    fs.Flush();
    continue;
}
```

I wanted to ask you if this method overwrite the file with new values if the file with this name already exist or do nothing because already exist this file?
I need to overwrite the file in eventuality that this file already exist but with old value.

Comment: FileMode.Append appends data if file exists or creates a new file if file doesn't exist. If you want to overwrite the file, use FileMode.Create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx) FileMode.Create

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the
>   file already exists, it will be overwritten. This requires
>   FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. FileMode.Create is equivalent
>   to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew;
>   otherwise, use Truncate. If the file already exists but is a hidden
>   file, an UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown.

Where as FileMode.Append

> Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or
>   creates a new file. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Append
>   permission. FileMode.Append can be used only in conjunction with
>   FileAccess.Write. Trying to seek to a position before the end of the
>   file throws an IOException exception, and any attempt to read fails
>   and throws a NotSupportedException exception.

So, you should use this

```
pic = (byte[])myPicutureFromDatabase;
using (var fs = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
       {
          fs.Write(pic);
          fs.Flush();
          continue;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No it appends the lines, you have specified it by writing `FileMode.Append`, you should specify `FileMode.Create` in order to append lines (or create a new file if it not exists)

Comment: thank you, I found the same solution right after posted the question. But thank you for the fast response.